# Get `Symbol`s of method parameters via reflection

Tags: scala, reflection

I want to call a method on an object via reflection, where each parameter of the method should  be set to a value specified its type. More specific: I have a `Map[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol,Any]` where `Symbol` is a type e.g. `List`, `Double`, `String` and `Any` is the instance to use.

Now, for each parameter of the method I want to query the map and set the parameter accordingly.

I used `typeOf[T].members.collect ...` to obtain the method `scala.reflect.MethodSymbol`, but I don't know how to obtain the correct `Symbol`. The elements in `method.paramss` are for example `val a` but not the `Symbol` of the type of `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`method.paramss` gives you a list of lists (one for each parameter list) that contain a `TermSymbol` for each argument. Each `TermSymbol` has a `typeSignature` method that returns a `Type`, which has a `typeSymbol` method that should give you the symbol you're looking for.

For example:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> class Foo { def foo(s: String, i: Int) = s * i }
defined class Foo

scala> val params = typeOf[Foo].member(newTermName("foo")).asMethod.paramss.head
params: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = List(value s, value i)

scala> params.map(_.typeSignature.typeSymbol)
res0: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = List(class String, class Int)
```

Which I think is what you want.